# Azure - uploading files to blob storage via shared hosting

Tags: upload, azure, hosting, shared, azure-blob-storage

Im struggling to find an answer to this. I have a website that is deployed in a shared hosting environment. I want to allow people to upload files to my azure blob storage account.

I have this working locally, using the storage emulator, however when I publish the site I get a Security Exception.

Is this actually possible under a shared hosting envrionment ?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

A bit more detail would help, in understanding how these uploads are taking place. That said, I'll make the assumption that people are uploading directly to Blob Storage, and not through your Website (or Web Service).

To allow direct uploads, you need to provide either a public blob or container (which everyone in the world can see), or create a temporary Shared Access Signature (SAS) on a specific blob or container, that grants access for a short time window.

If your app is Silverlight, then you are probably running into a cross-domain issue (and you'll need to correct that with an access policy).

If you provide more details around the way uploads are being sent, as well as the client and server technology, I can edit my answer to be more specific.